# No longer able to list all Drive files that are writable by a given user

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a PHP application that has been doing this nicely for some months now. Suddenly, at about 5:30 eastern time on 5/31, the list command I was running--which included

```
q=[the user ID I care about]+in+writers
```

no longer returns any Drive files. And sure enough, when I test that same code in the "Try This API" area of [the Files:list documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list), it no longer works there either.

The more-or-less exact call, via the Google PHP API client (https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client), version 1.1.7:

```
// $client is a legitimate Google API client
$my_id = 12121212121212121212; // my legitimate Google user ID
$this->drive = new \Google_Service_Drive($client);
$parameters = [
  'fields' => 'files(id, name, mimeType, createdTime, modifiedTime, parents), nextPageToken',
  'q' => 'trashed = false and "' . $my_id . '" in writers'
];
$response = $this->drive->files->listFiles($parameters);
$this->files = $response->getFiles();
```

At this point in the code, $this->files used to contain a long list of the files which $my_id was allowed to edit. Now--nothing.

The timing on this sure seems like a planned change by Google, but I can't figure out where on the Internet to look for confirmation. Has anyone else had the ability to list by membership in files' "writers" field removed? And if so, what's the workaround?

Comment: Could you please share the HTTP request format that you've been using? And, are these files located in Team Drive?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding!

Comment: ..apparently returns here submit the comment. I'm not totally clear on your question about the request format; perhaps it helps to show the exact call I'm using to get a response. Did that in an edit on the original question, but let me know if it doesn't clarify.

Comment: @Teyam, you seem to know what you're doing in this arena. Any idea of what might have changed here, and how I could get my results again?